# My auto-generated "dots" stick to the bottom of the screen after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I have this site (http://mc.wordquest.nl/green/dots.html) and I want to make dots floating from the bottom of the page into the air. In the first few seconds, it works fine. But after a second or 5, the dots stay in their place.
[Click here for the picture (of the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCeRj.png)

The dots are supposed to float to 100px above the bottom of the page. I do this by using a CSS animation (maybe not the best way of doing things, but I can work with it...).

The code I use for the page:

```js
  window.setInterval(function() {
   randomSquare();
  }, 100);

  var i = 0;

  function randomSquare() {
  
   //Set window height
   var w = window.innerWidth;
   var h = window.innerHeight;
  
   
   //Set dot x-position
   var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * w) + 1);
   var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * h) + 1);

   // Add a dot to follow the cursor
   dot = document.createElement('div');
   dot.className = "dot";
   dot.style.left = x + "px";
   dot.style.bottom = 10 + "px";

   i++;

   //Random color
   var COLOURS = ['#69D2E7', '#A7DBD8', '#E0E4CC', '#F38630',     '#FA6900', '#FF4E50', '#F9D423'];
    //    var color = "blue";
   var color = COLOURS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLOURS.length)];

   dot.style.backgroundColor = color;

   if (y < h * 0.97 && x < w * 0.97) {
    document.body.appendChild(dot);
   }
  };
```

```css
  body {
   height: 80%;
   width: 90%;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: Bold;
  }
  
  .dot {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: green;
   position: absolute;
   color: white;
   z-index: 1px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   animation: dots 2s linear;
  }
  
  @keyframes dots {
   0% {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
   }
   100% {
    /*     opacity: 0; */
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: 100px;
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <style>
 </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after reaching 100% the properties you defined in your keyframes won't stay applied to your animation. In order to do that, you need to set `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. What is more, it is important to notice that you infinitely adding elements to your DOM. That is a memory leak. Instead, after some time (animation completed) you should remove the element. (Or possibly have fixed number of dots, and re-use them) Consider following snippet, note that there is

```
setTimeout(function(){
          dot.remove();
        }, 2000)
```

Additionally, you forgot to add `var` keyword to `dot` variable, making it global.

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
        randomSquare();
    }, 100);

    var i = 0;

    function randomSquare() {

        //Set window height
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;


        //Set dot x-position
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * w) + 1);
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * h) + 1);

        // Add a dot to follow the cursor
        var dot = document.createElement('div');
        dot.className = "dot";
        dot.style.left = x + "px";
        dot.style.bottom = 10 + "px";
      
        i++;

        //Random color
        var COLOURS = ['#69D2E7', '#A7DBD8', '#E0E4CC', '#F38630',     '#FA6900', '#FF4E50', '#F9D423'];
//          var color = "blue";
        var color = COLOURS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLOURS.length)];

        dot.style.backgroundColor = color;

        if (y < h * 0.97 && x < w * 0.97) {
            document.body.appendChild(dot);
        }
      
        setTimeout(function(){
          dot.remove();
        }, 2000)
    };
```

```css
body {
        height: 80%;
        width: 90%;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: Bold;
    }

    .dot {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: green;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        z-index: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: dots 2s linear;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    }

    @keyframes dots {
        0% {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            opacity: 1;
            bottom: 0px;
        }
        100% {
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            bottom: 100px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To let the elements maintain their style at the end of the animation, add:

```
.dot {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```